# How to manage collection of enumeration in an entity with a composite id?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity with a composite id and a collection of enumeration, but i am unable to set JPA annotations to configure that correctly.

Here the SQL for the tables :

```sql
create table `ReadWriteRight` (
    `idProfil` bigint not null,
    `idState` bigint not null,
    `read` boolean,
    `write` boolean,
    primary key (`idProfil`, `idState`),
    constraint `FK_ReadWriteRight_Profil` foreign key(`idProfil`) REFERENCES `Profil`(`idProfil`),
    constraint `FK_ReadWriteRight_State` foreign key(`idState`) REFERENCES `State`(`idState`)
) engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8;

create table `AssoReadRight_Form` (
    `idProfil` bigint not null,
    `idState` bigint not null,
    `typeForm` varchar(50) not null,
    primary key (`idProfil`, `idState`, `typeForm`),
    constraint `FK_AssoReadRight_Form_Profil` foreign key(`idProfil`) REFERENCES `Profil`(`idProfil`),
    constraint `FK_AssoReadRight_Form_State` foreign key(`idState`) REFERENCES `State`(`idState`)
) engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8;

create table `AssoWriteRight_Form` (
    `idProfil` bigint not null,
    `idState` bigint` not null,
    `typeForm` varchar(50) not null,
    primary key (`idProfil`, `idState`, `typeForm`),
    constraint `FK_AssoWriteRight_Form_Profil` foreign key(`idProfil`) REFERENCES `Profil`(`idProfil`),
    constraint `FK_AssoWriteRight_Form_State` foreign key(`idState`) REFERENCES `State`(`idState`)
) engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8;
```

And here the Java with JPA annotations :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ReadWriteRight")
public class ReadWriteRight implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public enum TypeForm {
        Form1, Form2;
    }

    @Embeddable
    public static final class ReadWriteRightId implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "idProfil", nullable = false)
        private Profil profil;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "idState", nullable = false)
        private State state;

        [...]
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private ReadWriteRightId id;

    @Column(name = "read")
    private boolean read;

    @Column(name = "write")
    private boolean write;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = TypeForm.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "AssoReadRight_Form", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "idProfil", nullable = false), @JoinColumn(name = "idState", nullable = false)})
    @Column(name = "typeForm")
    private Set<TypeForm> formulairesLecture;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = TypeForm.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @CollectionTable(name = "AssoWriteRight_Form", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "idProfil", nullable = false), @JoinColumn(name = "idState", nullable = false)})
    @Column(name = "typeForm")
    private Set<TypeForm> formulairesEcriture;

    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem with some modifications :

First, I had to change the foreign key for my tables `AssoWriteRight_Form` and `AssoReadRight_Form` so that they link to the composite id from the table `ReadWriteRight`:

```sql
create table `AssoReadRight_Form` (
    `idProfil` bigint not null,
    `idState` bigint not null,
    `typeForm` varchar(50) not null,
    primary key (`idProfil`, `idState`, `typeForm`),
    constraint `FK_AssoReadRight_Form` foreign key(`idProfil`, `idState`) REFERENCES `ReadWriteRight`(`idProfil`, `idState`)
) engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8;

create table `AssoWriteRight_Form` (
    `idProfil` bigint not null,
    `idState` bigint` not null,
    `typeForm` varchar(50) not null,
    primary key (`idProfil`, `idState`, `typeForm`),
    constraint `FK_AssoWriteRight_Form` foreign key(`idProfil`, `idState`) REFERENCES `ReadWriteRight`(`idProfil`, `idState`)
) engine=InnoDB default charset=utf8;
```

I also had to change my JPA configuration so the `@JoinColumn` link correctly between the association table and the base table:

```java
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@ElementCollection(targetClass = TypeForm.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name = "AssoReadRight_Form", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "idProfil", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "idProfil"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "idState", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "idState")})
@Column(name = "typeForm")
private Set<TypeForm> formulairesLecture;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@ElementCollection(targetClass = TypeForm.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name = "AssoWriteRight_Form", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "idProfil", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "idProfil"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "idState", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "idState")})
@Column(name = "typeForm")
private Set<TypeForm> formulairesEcriture;
```